# get image from iphone, using phonegap camera api

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm new to Xcode and iPhone apps. I want to select an image from iPhone (camera or library) and send to php via ajax.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/iPhone:-Camera-API

I'm using the phonegap framework, Xcode iPhone SDK version 3.1.x.  On clicking button it calls function with parameter 0 or 1, but it does not initialize camera or display the library.

I checked the simulator virtual phone; there is no icon for camera, but the pictures album is there.

I used the same code as in the above link.

What do I do, what and how to check? any other functions to get photos using phonegap?

Answer (score 6):

The camera is not available in the iPhone Simulator.  Test with the Photo Album when running in the iPhone Simulator, and test the camera on an actual iPhone device.

Comment: Hi there, Is it possible to embed camera to a div?

Answer (score 3):

```
// JavaScript Document  //Get Picture stuff 
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM});

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}
// Called if something bad happens.
function onFail(message) {alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}





//  put in index.html    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

it shows this error in debug console:
2010-03-25 23:36:02.337 PhoneGap[7433:207] Camera.getPicture: Camera not available.

both are the same function Camera.getPicture pamameter only differs 0 or 1, but photos also not wokring!

Answer (score 0):

does not work from me on the actual phone either. Neither success or fail functions are called. I put a try/catch around getPicture, and it catches an exception saying "exception getting picture: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: GapCam". This is the same on the simulator and the phone. Any idears?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example on PhoneGap's API documentation and it works for me using an iPhone 4 device.  Here's my code:

```
function take_pic(){
  var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
  viewport.style.display = "";
  navigator.camera.getPicture(dump_pic, fail, { quality: 50 }); 
}

function dump_pic(data){
  var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
  console.log(data);
  viewport.style.display = "block";
  viewport.style.position = "absolute";
  viewport.style.top = "10px";
  viewport.style.left = "10px";
  document.getElementById("test_img").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
}
```